# How can I select an HTML element from JavaScript without knowing its ID?

Tags: javascript, html, select, image

I have an unknown number of `<img>` elements on my page with no IDs, and I need to be able to browse through them and set certain attributes based on a number of unpredictable factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   var currentImg = imgs[i];
   if (currentImg.somAttr) {
       // do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the code I would recommend (assuming it is a library agnostic site).

Answer (score 6):

You would use [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to browse through them as an array:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

This is an array of `img` elements, and you can treat it as if you were using the `getElementById()` function (i.e. you can still do the same operations on the elements, but you need to reference an element):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
```

If the factors you are speaking about are really complicated, I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (it's really powerful):

```
$('img[alt]').css('padding', '10px');
```

This would add a `10px` padding to every image with an `alt` attribute (I hope, as I'm notorious for posting almost-working code).

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Everyone forgets about [`document.images`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.images)...

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
  var img = document.images[i];

  if(img.src == "banner.gif") {
     img.alt = "Banner";
  }
  else if(img.alt == "Giraffe") {
     img.title = "15 feet tall!";
  }
}
```

If you need to get images within another element, you can use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
var fooImages = elem.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: @Giffyguy No it does not, but that can be done with `getElementsByTagName` (answer updated)

Answer (score 2):

You can use getElementsByTagName to get a list of the img tags:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1):

You can set name attribue for image tag and can perform any operation using document.getElementsByName.

for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElements()
  {
  var x=document.getElementsByName("x");
  alert(x.length);
  }
</script>

<input name="x" type="text" size="20" /><br />
<input name="x" type="text" size="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and search by element type $("img").each() to perform am operation on each element

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is probably your best bet.  Otherwise you'll have to traverse a dom tree and check for attributes manually.  Once you use jQuery you can select elements by attributes like name, class, the tag name (input, image, etc) and combinations of them.

```
$("image .className").attr(....
```

http://www.jquery.com

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer this without knowing more specifics, but have you considered using Jquery?